# how to save the response from the server in python?

Tags: python, json, regex, python-2.7, pcm

input.txt:

```
I am Hungry
I am going home
I am going to Germany
```

complete code :

```
 """Represent a part in a multipart messsage"""

    def __init__(self, name, contentType, data, paramName=None):

        super(Part, self).__init__()

        self.name = name

        self.paramName = paramName

        self.contentType = contentType

        self.data = data



    def encode(self):

        body = BytesIO()



        if self.paramName:

            body.write('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; paramName="%s"\r\n' % (self.name, self.paramName))

        else:

            body.write('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"\r\n' % (self.name,))



        body.write("Content-Type: %s\r\n" % (self.contentType,))

        body.write("\r\n")

        body.write(self.data)



        return body.getvalue()



class Request(object):

    """A handy class for creating a request"""

    def __init__(self):    

        super(Request, self).__init__()

        self.parameters = []



    def add_json_parameter(self, name, paramName, data):

        self.parameters.append(Part(name=name, paramName=paramName, contentType="application/json; charset=utf-8", data=data))



    def add_audio_parameter(self, name, paramName, data):

        self.parameters.append(Part(name=name, paramName=paramName, contentType="audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000", data=data))



    def encode(self):

        boundary = uuid.uuid4().hex

        body = BytesIO()



        for parameter in self.parameters:

            body.write("--%s\r\n" % (boundary,))

            body.write(parameter.encode())

            body.write("\r\n")



        body.write("--%s--\r\n" % (boundary,))



        return body.getvalue(), boundary



host = "mtldev08.nuance.com"

port = 443

uri = "/NmspServlet/"
Error_Status = 0


RequestData = """{

    "appKey": "9c9fa7201e90d3d96718bc3f36ce4cfe1781f2e82f4e5792996623b3b474fee2c77699eb5354f2136063e1ff19c378f0f6dd984471a38ca5c393801bffb062d6",

    "appId": "NMDPTRIAL_AutomotiveTesting_NCS61HTTP",

    "uId": "Alexander",

    "inCodec": "PCM_16_8K",

    "outCodec": "PCM_16_8K",

    "cmdName": "NVC_TTS_CMD",

    "appName": "Python",

    "appVersion": "1",

    "language": "eng-GB",

    "carrier": "carrier",

    "deviceModel": "deviceModel",

    "cmdDict": {

        "tts_voice": "Serena",

        "tts_language": "eng-GB",

        "locale": "canada",

        "application_name": "Testing Python Script",

        "organization_id": "NUANCE",

        "phone_OS": "4.0",

        "phone_network": "wifi",

        "audio_source": "SpeakerAndMicrophone",

        "location": "47.4925, 19.0513",

        "application_session_id": "1234567890",

        "utterance_number": "5",

        "ui_langugage": "en",

        "phone_submodel": "nmPhone2,1",

        "application_state_id": "45"        

    }

}"""



TEXT_TO_READ = """{

    "tts_type": "text",

    "tts_input": "DUMMY"

}"""

scriptPath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
scriptPath = os.path.dirname(scriptPath)
fileInput = os.path.join(scriptPath, "input.txt")
if not os.path.exists(fileInput):
    print "error message"
    Error_Status = 1
    sys.exit(Error_Status)
try:
    content = open(fileInput, "r")
except IOError:
    print "error message"
    Error_Status = 1
    sys.exit(Error_Status)
for line in content.readlines():
    line = line.strip('\n')
    if len(line):
        TEXT_TO_READ = json.loads(TEXT_TO_READ)
        TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"]=line
        TEXT_TO_READ = json.dumps(TEXT_TO_READ)
        print json.dumps(TEXT_TO_READ)
        #TEXT_TO_READ = json.loads(TEXT_TO_READ)
        #print TEXT_TO_READ

        request = Request()
        request.add_json_parameter("RequestData", None, RequestData)
        request.add_json_parameter("TtsParameter", "TEXT_TO_READ", TEXT_TO_READ)
        body, boundary = request.encode()

        try:
            h = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host, port)
        except (httplib.HTTPException, socket.error) as ex:
            print "Error: %s" % ex

        h.set_debuglevel(0)

        headers = {

            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=%s" % (boundary,),

            "Connection": "Keep-Alive",

        }

        h.request('POST', uri, body, headers)
        res = h.getresponse()
        data = """MIME-Version: 1.0
        Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--Nuance_NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq
        """ + res.read()

        msg = email.message_from_string(data)

        for index, part in enumerate(msg.walk(), start=1):
            content_type = part.get_content_type()
            payload = part.get_payload()

            if content_type == "audio/x-wav" and len(payload):
                with open('line.pcm'.format(index), 'w') as f_pcm:
                    f_pcm.write(payload)
            elif content_type == "application/json":
                with open('line.txt'.format(index), 'w') as f_json:
                    f_json.write(payload)

sys.exit(Error_Status)
```

I want to read the input.txt line by line and send that as a request to the server and later save the response respectively. I am reading only the information which I needed and saving it in pcm file and .txt file but I am reading it line by line but the output is not generating a line.txt and line.pcm file. It works for just one input example (input.txt): I am going to Germany
but my input.txt contains - this will be the request

```
I am Hungry
I am going home
I am going to Germany
```

I think, I am making mistake in saving the response. someone help me. it is not generating line.txt and line.pcm for three inputs.

Comment: whats "content_type" when you print it? and could you provide an example of "input.txt"

Comment: i added complete code and input.txt. input.txt contains just a text as shown above